# Extra text when using jsondecode

Tags: matlab

I am trying to come to the point where I create a graph on a given data that I am supposed to read from a text file.
So I use in my code *fopen* to open the text file, *textscan* to scan it, than make a string out of it and by using *split* I want to cut of the first part of every line and use the second part so that I can *decode* it into json and then use the information.
So my text file consists of two lines of information:

> 123456.99 :: working completed: result=0 , data ="{"day":"monday", "breakfast":"sandwich"}"
>   123456.99 :: working completed: result=0 , data ="{"day":"tuesday", "breakfast":"bread"}"

The first part of my code:

```
fileID  = fopen('test1');
text = textscan(fileID, '%s', 'delimiter','\n','whitespace','');
strLog = string(text{1});
res = split(strLog, "data =");
json_str = res(:, 2)
```

And as a result I get a 2x1 string array. Output:

> json_str =
>
> 2×1 string array
>
> ```
> ""{"day":"monday", "breakfast":"sandwich"}""
> ""{"day":"tuesday", "breakfast":"bread"}""
> ```

This is where I got stuck.
My first idea was to call *cellfun* and apply *jsondecode*. 
But I got

> Error using jsondecode JSON syntax error at line 1, column 4
>   (character 4): extra text.

But it makes no sence to me, since that should be the " from "day" which for json should be okay!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `json_str` you have quote marks `"` at the start and end. These need to be removed for `jsondecode` to work.  For example `J = jsondecode(json_str{1}(2:end-1))`.

You can then use `cellfun` to process all elements. For example,

```
S = cellfun(@(x)jsondecode(x(2:end-1)),json_str)
```

Comment: on the spot! is there a simple way to make it apply to all the lines? more general, in case my text file has 1000 lines not just 1 or 2

Comment: @RadoslavIvanov As you suggested you could use `cellfun` to process all elements of `json_str`